# How to correctly type the return value of factory method

Tags: typescript

I have a base class which looks like this

```
class Base {
    protected constructor() {}

    static create() {
         return new this;
    }
}
```

Now, when I extend this class and try to initialise I get a typescript error

```
class Bar extends Base {
    magic() {}
}

let bar: Bar;
bar = Bar.create(); // <-- Typescript error
```

The error is

```
  Property 'magic' is missing in type 'Base' but required in type 'Bar'
```

So it seems that typescript expects that the returned value of `create` is an instance of `Base`, but is in fact `Bar`.

I can fix this as follows

```
class Base {
    protected constructor() {}

    static create<T>(): T {
         return new this as T;
    }
}
```

and

```
bar = Bar.create<Bar>();
```

I would expect that all this is not necessary, because it is pretty clear what the return type is. But how can I tell typescript what the return type is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you do not override create in the subclass.

```
static create() {
    return new this;
}
```

This method has an implicit return type of `Base`.

In an non-static method, you could return `this`, but it's not possible here.

The Polymorphic `this` for static methods is a [long known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863)